# Highcharts with angularjs: smooth transition of bars when updating values

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I found this example ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rSHN4/1/)) to update a series.

```
$scope.chartConfig.series[0].data = rnd;
```

However the bars change instantly instead of smoothly when you click on the button 'Update Series'.
Is it possible to have smooth transition effect of the bars like in this example  ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/animation-duration/)) while keeping AngularJS?

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update(i % 2 ? 200 : 0);
```

Kind regards,
James.

Comment: See my comment form second post.

Answer (score 0):

check this api
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.animation

add animation to series object like, where duration in milliseconds

```
series: [{
        data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7,10, 15, 12, 8, 7],
        animation: {
            duration: 1000
        }
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rSHN4/3/

Comment: It will not work, because highcharts-ng update upoints in different way (by update array) and using $watch. Animations are disabled.